Is it possible to selectively add input devices to a running Xorg server?
I'm using Xorg with AutoAddDevices disabled, because I have many input devices on my server, which mustn't all be added to my physical session.
The input devices I need are pre-configured in the xorg.conf.
Everything works great, until my input device disconnects (for example due to EMI). And after that happens, when it connects back, it is not being taken up automatically by X. The Xorg server becomes absolutely uncontrollable, and I can't even switch the VT. I have to log in via serial port or SSH, just to kill that Xorg server (together with all the programs which were running with it). After doing that, the screen returns to the TTY and the input starts to work. I start Xorg from scratch then.
Is there any solution to the problem, other than enabling AutoAddDevices?

Did you try CTRL+ALT+BackSpace to kill & restart your X server ?

@admstg yes, and it does not work. But I'm able to successfully use Alt+SysRQ+K (aka SAK) to kill tasks on the current TTY, which ends up killing X. But it doesn't solve the problem, either. It's not normal to have to restart X every time the input device reconnects.

I suppose you'll have to resort to "blacklisting" instead of "whitelisting", i.e., option Ignore of InputClass sections.

@TomYan thanks for the advice, but do I need to enable AutoAddDevices for that?

@melonfsck Yeah, the idea is that since AutoAddDevices being disabled seems to be culprit, so you probably want to try have it enabled back and adopt a "blacklisting" approach instead. (My guess is that when you disable AutoAddDevices, you'd be effectively disabling hotplugging as well, i.e., it is not a bug but an expected side effect.)
